# "Identify" terminology

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition

What does it mean to "identify" two objects in algebra, as distinct from having an isomorphism or automorphism between them?

I was led to think about this while reading Stewart's Galois Theory, where there are often sentences such as *"A field extension is a monomorphism $\iota \colon K \twoheadrightarrow L$, where $K$, $L$ are fields. Usually we identify $K$ with its image $\iota(K)$, and in this case $K$ becomes a subfield of $L$."*

Comment: In my opinion, identification means that a specific isomorphism between two objects is being held in mind, but may be suppressed in the notation for the sake of simplicity/legibility. In any case, the particular isomorphism that is being used must be clear from the context.

Comment: Yes (to ivanpenev's explanation). Another example would be when the field of rational numbers is constructed as a collection of equivalence classes of pairs of integers, and the integers are "embedded" in this field by "identifying" each integer $n$ with the equivalence class $\overline{(n,1)}$.